# Initial stages of MVP, is the bootstrap file efficient coding

Tags: php, mvc, slim

I am attempting to put my new OOP skills to the test and am eventually going to build a simple OOP login/registration system.

However as I am making use of OOP I have decided to make my own simple MVC.

Here is my layout of my directory

```
root-directory/
   .htaccess
   app/
      Config/
      Controllers/
      Models/
      Views/
      Lib/
        Vendor/
        composer.json
      bootstrap/
         app.php
   public/
      assets/
        js/
        css/
        img/
      index.php
      .htaccess
```

I have my app file in the `Bootstrap` folder I have written my code in a manor so it checks if the `_GET` super variable has anything in it, if it doesn't then set the `$this->controller = 'home'` and set the `$this->method = 'index'`

Here is my Bootstrap/app.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../Lib/vendor/autoload.php';

class App
{

    private $controller;
    private $method;
    private $requests;

    public function __construct($requests)
    {
        $this->requests = $requests;

        $this->requests = $this->requests['PATH_INFO'];

        $this->requests = explode('/',$this->requests);

        if ($this->requests[0] == '')) {

            $this->controller = 'home';

        } else {

            $this->controller = $this->requests[0];

        }



        if ($this->requests[1] == '' ) {

            $this->method = 'index';

        } else {

            $this->method = $this->requests[1];

        }

        echo $this->controller;
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $this->method;

        die();

    }
}
```

Here is my index.php file

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

require __DIR__ . '/../app/Bootstrap/app.php';

$b = new \App\Bootstrap\App($_GET);
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Is this a correct way of starting this project? As my next step would be to create a base controller and then link the url to the controller.

If this is not a correct/appropriate coding manor for OOP would a good correction include changing the `RewriteRule` to include to variables for the controller and method.

Comment: Voting to close since we don't review folder structures, just code.

Comment: @syb0rg sorry about that, will edit it once I got some code in it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add another folder named `libraries` inside of `app`.
2. Follow a particular case convention. Like don't have `config` (all small) and other folders with first letter capitalized. Either all small or all first letter capitalized.
3. Add a `language` folder within `app`. That will store your language strings within each language folder. For example, you can have a `language/english` folder & similarly for other languages.

I like that you have separated the `public` folder.